# Skaffold rebuilding images instead of using cache (Github Actions)

Tags: caching, github-actions, skaffold

I am new to skaffold and trying to understand why Skaffold is not building images from '~/.skaffold/cache' and rebuilds new images when running on github actions. When running locally, I can see the `Found Locally` when Skaffold is checking cache.
Following is my github workflow - https://github.com/rajivsavroop/GH_skaffold_example/blob/test-skaffold-cache/.github/workflows/example.yaml

Thank you in advance.

Tried -https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/4842 but not working.

Expecting Skaffold to use cached images instead of building new ones on every run in Github Actions.